# How to change a JavaScript object's field names?

Tags: javascript, object, field

Lets say we have 2 Javascript objects and an array:

```
var rawData = {
    "dModel": "Deluxe",
    "sizeMB": 256,
};

var displayNames = {
    "dModel": "Device Model",
    "sizeMB": "Size(MB)"
};

var fieldNames = ["dModel", "sizeMB"];
```

I want to change the field names in rawData according to the mapping indicated by displayNames, the final result should be:

```
var data = {
    "Device Model": "Deluxe",
    "Size(MB)": 256,
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `rawData` to build the new `data` object and use `displayNames` as a lookup table for the new property names:

```
var data = {};
for (var p in rawData)
    data[displayNames[p]] = rawData[p];
```

Comment: You're creating a global variable `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var oldKey in displayNames)
{
    var newKey = displayNames[oldKey];
    rawData[newKey] = rawData[oldKey];
    delete rawData[oldKey];
}
```

Comment: This will only work if displayNames does not contain a key that is already in rawData. Although the OP asked to change the fieldnames of rawData, it's safer to create a new object.